# How to read every .csv file in R and export them into single large file

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi so I have a data in the following format

```
101,20130826T155649
------------------------------------------------------------------------
3,1,round-0,10552,180,yellow
12002,1,round-1,19502,150,yellow
22452,1,round-2,28957,130,yellow,30457,160,brake,31457,170,red
38657,1,round-3,46662,160,yellow,47912,185,red
```

and I have been reading them and cleaning/formating them by this code

```
b <- read.table("sid-101-20130826T155649.csv", sep = ',', fill=TRUE, col.names=paste("V", 1:18,sep="") )
b$id<- b[1,1]
b<-b[-1,]
b<-b[-1,]
b$yellow<-B$V6
```

and so on
There are about 300 files like this, and ideally they will all compiled without the first two lines, since the first line is just id and I made a separate column to identity these data. Does anyone know how to read these table quickly and clean and format the way I want then compile them into a large file and export them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to read all the files, clean and format them, and store the resulting data frames in a list. Then use `do.call` to combine all of the data frames into single large data frame.

```
# Get vector of files names to read
files.to.load = list.files(pattern="csv$")

# Read the files
df.list = lapply(files.to.load, function(file) {
   df = read.table(file, sep = ',', fill=TRUE, col.names=paste("V", 1:18,sep=""))
   ... # Cleaning and formatting code goes here
   df$file.name = file  # In case you need to know which file each row came from
   return(df)
})

# Combine into a single data frame
df.combined = do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

Comment: So I tried your code and I got the Error message saying Error in read.table.... more columns than column names. I think maybe it's because some files have more than 18 columns, so when it tried to put 23 columns instead the error messages disappeared. but it says the another error message that "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "file.name", value = "sid-106R2-20131014T143355.csv") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0 . What does this mean

Comment: The second error sounds like one of the files you tried to read doesn't contain any data (`data has 0` refers to zero rows), or at least R didn't read in any rows of data.

Comment: Thanks I just found out that one of the file is empty. And I found out that if I have 33 columns for read.table then the code reads fine. But as I edit to the cleaning and formatting part, another error creeps up for the
    df.combined= do.call(rbind, df.list). It says Error in match.name(class, names(xi)): names do not match previous names. what does this mean?

Comment: ok so I think I found the problem, which is the code in the formatting part
    df<- df[-nrow(df)]. so how I'd get the names do not match previous names error for the rbind after that code. Any way to prevent that from happening? maybe with another code to remove the last line of every file?

Comment: That means that not all of the data frames have the same column names. You can only `rbind` data frames that have the same column names.

Comment: To remove last line of every data frame, you can add `df = df[-nrow(df), ]` inside the `lapply` function.

Comment: You can stack data frames with differing column names using the `bind_rows` function from the `dplyr` package. You'll end up with a data frame whose column names are the union of all the column names in the list of data frames. `bind_rows` will set cell values to `NA` for data frames that don't have a given column. Syntax would be `df.combined=bind_rows(df.list)`.