# Exporting Items from List into Single .csv File R

Tags: r

I have a list which contains vectors that I would like to export as a single .csv file containing all vectors as named colums.

For instance, if I have, simply, four vectors containing ten items from hypothetical cluster analyses of four models containing a variable number data points created by

```
veglist=list.files(pattern="TXT") #create list of files
veg=lapply(veglist,read.csv,header=T,row.names=1) #read list of files
vegbc=lapply(veg,vegdist,method="bray") #create dissimilarity matrix from each file
av=lapply(vegbc,agnes,method="average") #do clustering analysis with each dissimilarity mat
av2=lapply(av,cutree,k=2) #cut the hierarchical analysis at 2 groups level
```

when I type in fix(av2) I would see:

```
list(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),c(1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2),c(1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

If I type in av2 I see

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 

[[2]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 

[[3]]
[1] 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 

[[4]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I have tried following this example [How to read every .csv file in R and export them into single large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608177/how-to-read-every-csv-file-in-r-and-export-them-into-single-large-file). This did not work.

I think the underlying problem is that my vectors are not the same size. What I want to do is output the vectors into a single table that looks something like:

```
a b c d
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 2 1
1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2     2
2     2
      2
```

Where a,b,c,d are in place of my actual names. Preferably it would look prettier than this, but I could work with it.

I apologize for the very long question, but I was trying to provide enough of an example to go by. I am also sorry if this has a very easy answer, but I am not yet good with R. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did analyze the problem correctly. There is a `length<-` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need to extend each vector to the length of the maximum length-ed vector and then you could `cbind` them together so that `write.csv` would send them out as "columns":

```
> maxlength <- max(sapply(l, length))
> mat <- cbind(sapply(l, `length<-`, maxlength))
> mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1
 [3,]    1    1    1    1
 [4,]    1    1    2    1
 [5,]    1    1    1    2
 [6,]    1    2    2    1
 [7,]    2    2    2    2
 [8,]    2    2    2    2
 [9,]    2    2    2    2
[10,]    2    2    2    2
[11,]    2   NA   NA    2
[12,]    2   NA   NA    2
[13,]   NA   NA   NA    2
> write.csv(mat, file="mycsv.csv")
```

Which looks like this in a text editor (and would get imported into Excel properly.):

```
"","V1","V2","V3","V4"
"1",1,1,1,1
"2",1,1,1,1
"3",1,1,1,1
"4",1,1,2,1
"5",1,1,1,2
"6",1,2,2,1
"7",2,2,2,2
"8",2,2,2,2
"9",2,2,2,2
"10",2,2,2,2
"11",2,NA,NA,2
"12",2,NA,NA,2
"13",NA,NA,NA,2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can do:

```
l <- list(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),c(1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2),c(1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
maxlength <- max(sapply(l, length))
df <- data.frame(sapply(l, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, (maxlength - length(x))))))
df

   X1 X2 X3 X4
1   1  1  1  1
2   1  1  1  1
3   1  1  1  1
4   1  1  2  1
5   1  1  1  2
6   1  2  2  1
7   2  2  2  2
8   2  2  2  2
9   2  2  2  2
10  2  2  2  2
11  2 NA NA  2
12  2 NA NA  2
13 NA NA NA  2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
m1 <- stri_list2matrix(l)
mode(m1) <- "integer"
m1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    1    2    1
# [5,]    1    1    1    2
# [6,]    1    2    2    1
# [7,]    2    2    2    2
# [8,]    2    2    2    2
# [9,]    2    2    2    2
#[10,]    2    2    2    2
#[11,]    2   NA   NA    2
#[12,]    2   NA   NA    2
#[13,]   NA   NA   NA    2
```

Comment: Somehow, this did not work for me. It ended up adding a bunch of rows full of NA to my data. I know it was supposed to fill in the gaps, but it added rows that were not there. I'll keep picking at it, because I probably did something wrong.